# K-means Algorithm with multiple parameters

Tags: java, algorithm, k-means

I have a set of points on the map. I'm trying to create clusters. Along with the distance, I'm considering the maximum cost (as another parameter) of the each cluster.

Please find the below code snippet.

```
private void assignCluster(List<Cluster> finalClusters, List<Node> clusterNodes, int maxCostLimit) {
    double max = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double min = max;
    int clusterIndex = 0;
    double distance = 0.0;

    for (Node node : clusterNodes) {
        min = max;
        for (int i = 0; i < finalClusters.size(); i++) {
            Cluster cluster = finalClusters.get(i);
            distance = Point.getDistanceBetweenPoints(node.getPoint(), cluster.getPoint());
            if (distance < min && (cluster.getTotalCost() + node.getCost()) <= maxCostLimit) {
                min = distance;
                clusterIndex = i;
            }
        }
        if (min != max) {
            Cluster cluster = finalClusters.get(clusterIndex);
            cluster.setTotalCost(cluster.getTotalCost() + node.getCost());
            cluster.addClusterNode(node);
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to create clusters, it is going to infinite loop. Alternatively, two points on the map are getting assigned to the two different clusters. In each iteration, the centroids of these two clusters are changing. 
Please suggest me, How can I achieve this?

**EDITS**

**Cluster.java**

```
public class Cluster{
    private List<Node> clusterNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    private Integer totalCost = 0;
    private Point2D point;

         //getters and setters
}
```

**Point.java**

```
public class Point{
    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;

        // getters and setters

       //method to find the distance between 2 points
}
```

I'm referring this link for basic Kmeans Algorithm : http://www.dataonfocus.com/k-means-clustering-java-code/

Comment: Could you post your code for class Cluster and Point

Comment: It sounds to me like you're falling into a local optima. Correct if I am wrong but I suppose you're generating your centroid randomnly - at least you should. So I believe that you need a mechanism that will check state between the two iterations. For example you should able to detect if you're centroid has move from (A1,B1) to (A2,B2) and then back to (A1,B1). In such a case you need to create a new centroid. Anyway posting more code would be helpful.

Comment: Can you also post the code where you update the centroids, once you have called `assignCluster()`

Comment: How do you generate the cluster centroids after the method assignCluster is called? And with the introduction of a "cost" of nodes you have some points that aren't assigned to clusters at all, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile (missing return statement). Please correct.

Comment: Can you post the source code for the `Cluster` class, please?

Comment: From your code I cannot tell which loop is infinite. Nor can I tell how this coude is used - I cannot see the overall picture.

Comment: @Ironluca I have added Point and Cluster code

Comment: @freefall Yes, I'm checking the difference in centroid after each iteration. I'm referring to the above link for basic Kmeans algorithm.

Comment: @SantiGil Please check the edited code.

Comment: @Wallkan No, All points are assigning to any one of the clusters because I'm deciding the number of clusters based on cost only. Problem is that some points(If two points are approximately at same distance from two clusters) are assigning to other cluster alternatively. so every time there will be a change in the centroid.

Comment: @Bohemian I have posted the pseudocode. Please refer the above link

Comment: @PiotrR The basic Kmeans algorithm works with the distance between two points. I have added another parameter "cost". while assigning to the cluster, I'm checking both distance and the cost.

Comment: One observation, in your code you are initializing min and max to MAX double value and then in the for loop you are assigning min=distance (if the condition is true) i.e. the distance between the point and (probably) cluster centroid. Now, what I feel, this would be sensetive to input sequencing. For example, if the first data point has a large distance, then subsequent data points will not be included in the cluster. On the other hand if the first point generates a smaller distance, then it may not give proper cluester. Unless I am missing something in getDistanceBetweenPoints call.

Comment: @Ironluca As you said, If the first data point has a large distance, still it goes subsequent data points to find the smaller distance.  Even I have checked the points in each cluster after some iteration(say after 500 iterations for 2000 nodes). I'm getting the optimized clusters.

Comment: I can't see `Cluster.point` being updated anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the *K*-means algorithm can be shown to never repeat an assignment of nodes to clusters from a previous iteration.

Maybe this is possible in your case, due to the extra constraint of costs that you have introduced that is traditionally not present when using *K*-means, but maybe it still isn't, I'm not sure.

I am wondering about how you are using this `assignCluster()` method for which you have provided the code. Do you have another loop around it which keeps calling `assignCluster()` with `finalClusters =` a list of the latest assignments of clusters, and `clusterNodes =` a list of all nodes, and keeps looping until it ends up with an assignment that is equal to the previous one?

If so, are you sure that `cluster.addClusterNode()` correctly removes the node from its' previous cluster (as I assume it should if you implemented it as described above?). Another thing to look at may be the `(cluster.getTotalDemand() + node.getCost())` calculation. I suspect that, if you happen to be looking at the cluster that this node is already in, you may not want to include `node.getCost()` in that calculation, since it'll be counted double if it's *also* included in `cluster.getTotalDemand()`.

I had to make some assumptions about what exactly you want the code to do, or how you implemented other methods for which the code is not shown... so you'll have to point out if there are any errors in my assumptions.

Comment: Basic Kmeans Algo works with distance. I have added another parameter cost. While assigning a node to the cluster, I'm checking the distance and costLimit as well. It is similar like creating the equally sized clusters.

Comment: @NVG does every node have the same cost? if not, can you try changing it such that every node does have the same cost, and see if in that case you no longer get stuck in an infinite loop? I suspect the alternating assignments are only possible when nodes can have different costs... and if that is the case, you can probably avoid the infinite loop by keeping a history of assignments of nodes to clusters of the last few iterations (more than one), and checking if the latest assignment is equal to any of the most recent X ones

Comment: Yes, I have tried by assigning the cost 1 to every node. Still, it is same :-(

Comment: @NVG can you post the code of the loop that calls the `assignCluster` function? following the link you provided, this should be the `calculate` method. I think the issue must be there

Comment: Yes, while loop inside the calculate method.

Comment: @NVG can you post that code? I have tried mixing your code in the OP with the code in the link, and I didn't get any infinite loops. So the problem must be in places where I had to guess what your implementation looks like, which is probably that function

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the the code you provided with your question and through the link, I cannot see any reason for an infinite loop (assuming that you adapted the code correctly) except of the possibility, that the total number of clusters multiplied with the maximum cost per cluster is smaller than the total cost of all nodes together. You could check that by iterating over all nodes before entering the loop.

Another problem could be, that you forgot to reset the `totalCost` per cluster in your `clearClusters()` method, but I think that would not lead to an infinite loop.

Why is your centroid of class-type `Point2D` and not an object of your own `Point` class?